# tibco xslt not accepting html script

Tags: xslt, tibco

I have to convert one xml to html page. I read that xml and mapped to transform xml. I have added html formatting tags in xslt. But it is not reflecting in page. I am getting data of xml in one line side by side. The html code not working what i have given. So any one can let me know how to transform xml to html, is there any other solution ?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that will help us answer. Start with showing what you did, a small example of input XML, XSLT you wrote, and output XML, with a sample of the expected output XML and where it goes wrong. Welcome at SO, take a minute to read the [faq] and [ask], please, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have added that "tibco xslt " in title of this question ....

```
   when working on tibco bw, I have to convert xml into html webpage; so i have used html code along with xslt transformation in xslt activity and also referenced it in transform activity.  but the resulting html is not as required, all the elements of xml are coming in html side by side;  

   but when i used this same html code out side of tibco, it is working fine as it is showing in a well formatted table.....
```

Then my question is will tibco xslt execute html code or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about using xslt transform activity for parsing a xml into html file.

Try parsing  xml and then write file activity . You can alter the content of the file as per your requirement with tags and data from the parsed xml file.